# Green's function of laplascian in 3D.

Tags: analysis, heat-equation

It is about heat equation in 3D.
How to prove, that 
$$w(M,M_0)=\frac{1}{\lambda r(M,M_0)}$$
is a solution of
$$\lambda \nabla^2w(M,M_0)+4\pi \delta(M,M_0)=0$$
?

I understand that I should integrate it somehow in spherical coordinates.

$$\nabla^2 f 
= {1 \over r^2} {\partial \over \partial r}
  \left(r^2 {\partial f \over \partial r} \right) 
+ {1 \over r^2 \sin \theta} {\partial \over \partial \theta}
  \left(\sin \theta {\partial f \over \partial \theta} \right) 
+ {1 \over r^2 \sin^2 \theta} {\partial^2 f \over \partial \varphi^2}.$$

$$\nabla w =\frac{2}{\lambda r} $$

But the integral 
$$\iiint \frac{2}{r}r^2sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$
diverges.